# Transfer Files using Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, excel-2016

I had a powershell script which used to transfer xlsx files to SQL Server in already existing tables. Later on, the IT team shifted to Office 365. The excel files used to have a column which having date format of a particular month. The transfer still works, but due to Excel 2016, the date format changes internally when the data gets into SQL table.

For eg: mm-dd-yyyy format gets changed to dd-mm-yyyy format when the dd < 12. Otherwise the format remains same.

There are large number of files which get transferred. and I don't want to change the date format later on In SQL as I have to deal with various formats altogether.

It is not the issue with earlier versions of EXCEL. I will appreciate if anyone suggest a workaround to keep the data intact while transferring from Excel to SQL?

Comment: Do your Excel columns contain *text* that looks like a date, or do they contain actual dates, i.e. *numbers* that are formatted as a date?

Comment: I thought Excel bases its default date formatting options on the regional settings in Windows you specified. Don't own the 2016 version so can't test it. But you could verify what happens if you change that?

Comment: The Excel columns contains text that look like a date @Tomalak

Comment: Then that's what you need to change. If that's not possible, change the date format to a sensible one. (Hint: The only sensible format to transport a date value in string form is `YYYY-MM-DD`. Every other representation is for human consumption and should not be used as a transfer format between technical systems.)

Comment: I agree with Tomalak.  `YYYY-MM-DD` is a better date format. One just never sees a `YYYY-DD-MM` format being used, so there's never confusion.

Comment: And that I have to modify in the excel file only ? Just wanted to clarify that it happens due to excel 2016. It happens because it understands the column format as date by itself, not the case with Excel 2013

Comment: There is an Excel trick to stop it from messing with formats: (1) Select required area, copy and paste it to notepad. (2) Clear that area by clicking rubber - clear both data and formats (3) Then select "Text" formatting on the toolbar for that selected empty excel area. (4) Copy data back from notepad. Now Excel will not try to format dates.